# How are number theory and C*-algebras connected?

Tags: nt.number-theory, c-star-algebras

I came across this [research profile](https://scholars.uow.edu.au/display/aidan_sims) where under Research Overview, it states that

> These days C*-algebra theory is a very active area of mathematical research in its own right, and enjoys deep connections with other areas of mathematics such as symbolic dynamics, ergodic theory, group theory and even number theory.

My question is how C*-algebras and number theory are connected and if this is an active area of research?

Answer (score 7):

- [$C^∗$-algebras
  associated with the $ax+b$-semigroup over $\mathbb{N}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611541) (2006)
- [Ring $C^*$-algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4861v1) (2009)
- [$K$-theory for ring $C^*$-algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4296) (2012)
- [$C^*$-algebras from actions of congruence monoids on rings of algebraic integers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04075) (2019)
- [On $K$-theoretic invariants of semigroup $C^*$-algebras from actions of congruence monoids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00445) (2019)

  These papers associate C*-algebras to rings and study the inner structure of these ring C*-algebras.  The
  generators of the corresponding $K$-theory turn out to be determined
  by prime numbers. Several connections to algebraic number theory are worked out in section 6 of the 2009 paper.

Comment: While I appreciate your list was meant to be indicative not exhaustive, worth pointing out that there has been more recent work strengthening some of the earlier results: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00445 which you could add to the list

Comment: thanks for the pointer; two 2019 references added, this might also go some way to answering the second question of the OP: _"is this is an active area of research?"_

Answer (score 6):

I think the most prominent example of this is [Connes' work on the Riemann hypothesis from a C*-algebra perspective](https://www.alainconnes.org/docs/imufinal.pdf).